# How can I automate control of a Remote Windows Client

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywinauto

I am trying to automate a backup process on a remote server, after logging in on the website with selenium, it launches a Remote windows client and a chrome accept popup,

ive managed to click on the chrome popup with pywinauto, but cant figure out the remote client window.  SWAPY does not have any drop down options for the window and this code:

```
app = pywinauto.application.Application()
app.connect(title=u'Computer - \\\\Remote', class_name='Transparent Windows Client')
app.Window_(title=u'Computer - \\\\Remote', class_name='Transparent Windows Client').PrintControlIdentifiers()
```

Returns:

```
Control Identifiers:
Transparent Windows Client - 'Windows Security - \\Remote'    (L1702, T282, R2131, B585)
['Windows Security - \\\\RemoteTransparent Windows Client', 'Transparent Windows Client', 'Windows Security - \\\\Remote']
child_window(title="Windows Security - \\Remote", class_name="Transparent Windows Client")
```

Which doesnt leave me much to work with. Does that mean im out of luck on this method?

I would really prefer to have the automation running reliably without relying on a "click on x and y coord" on the screen sort of method.  Any help appreciated.